# NSTableCell setDataCell disables editing

Tags: nstableview, nstablecolumn

I have a `NSTableView` which I dynamically add columns. I've just added a call to `setDataCell` to customize my cell. The code looks like:

```
for(NSUInteger columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < resultSet.columNames.count; ++columnIndex)
{
    NSTableColumn * newColumn = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", columnIndex]];

    [newColumn.headerCell setAlignment: NSCenterTextAlignment];
    [newColumn.headerCell setStringValue: resultSet.columNames[columnIndex]];
    [newColumn setDataCell: [[HSDisclosureTextFieldCell alloc] init]];
    [newColumn setEditable: YES];

    [resultsTableView addTableColumn: newColumn];
    if(newColumn.width < 60) [newColumn sizeToFit];
} // End of column loop
```

If I remove the call to `setDataCell` then I can still double click my entry and edit it.

I have minimized the `HSDisclosureTextFieldCell` contains the following (no overrides):

```
@interface HSDisclosureTextFieldCell : NSTextFieldCell
{
}
```

But I still cannot double click to edit the field anymore.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out even though I am doing:

```
[newColumn setEditable: YES];
```

and have:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

implemented, I needed to switch my `setDataCell` to be:

```
HSDisclosureTextFieldCell * cell = [[HSDisclosureTextFieldCell alloc] init];
[cell setEditable: YES];
[newColumn setDataCell: cell];
```

Now that I have done that, everything seems to be working properly.